In ArcGIS Pro I wish to bold numeric values in my label based on if they are above a certain number
I wish to bold numeric values in my label based on if they are above a certain number in an ArcGIS Pro feature class. I am currently using vbscript for my labeling expression but am open to Arcade, jscript, or Python as well. I have no code that I am using.

Please [Edit] the question to provide the VBScript code  you are trying to use.

You need to create two different label classes.
Here I have one class labeled bold numbers and values over or equal to 10 are bold.  I have another class called default where values less than 10 are regular font and smaller sized font.


Of course, you can alter the typeface, fonts, and font sizes as you wish in the label class symbol area.

Here is what my label classes look like...

